# Lookbehind assertion regex in atom editor

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I try to use a lookbehind assertion in the atom editor. My text is the following:

```
            <stop color="rgb(0,0,153)"       value = "0.13"/>
            <stop color="rgb(0,0,180)"       value = "0.17"/>
            <stop color="rgb(0,0,223)"       value = "0.25"/>
```

I can do a lookahead assertion with `.*(?=color\=)`. It selects everything before "color=". But if I try the lookbehind assertion `.*(?<=color\=)` atom tells me "Invalid regular expression". It seems that atom does not recognize `<`or `>` as special character, because it shows it the same color as common letters and numbers. I also can't use the once-only subexpression `?>`.

Since I don't really find a hint which flavor of regex is used in atom I don't know which regex I should use instead. Apparently one without `>` in it...

I know that this is xml and that I could extract the values with xml methods, but this is not part of what I want to achieve here.

Comment: shouldn't it be `(?<!regex)` ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you're reporting a bug in your editor, rather than having a problem with your code.  It really doesn't matter if your editor thinks your syntax is valid, it matters if the language you're coding in thinks its valid.  What language are you working in?  What errors, if any, do you get when you run your code through that language's compiler/interpreter?

Comment: You are right, knowing which flavor of regex is used by atom would help me. But I did not find any information about this. I added this to my question. But maybe I should ask the developers on their site.

Comment: @sweaver2112: `(?<!regex)` produces the same error message.

Comment: probly not available. javascript has no lookbehinds for example...

Comment: a non lookaround solution may work, but you've not described a problem per se.

Comment: @sweaver2112: you are right. Found that Atom uses Javascript RE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](https://discuss.atom.io/t/missing-regular-expression-summary-documentation/24399) thread in the atom discussion forum shows, that information about the regex dialect is indeed still missing in the official documentation. But they write in the discussion that Atom uses Javascript regex. And Javascript regex has no lookbehind implemented, while in contrast lookahead is implemented.

Hence you have to use a solution without lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

As of late, lookahead and lookbehind work in Atom.  Please see the documentation for Javascript for details.

https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

One example that works in Atom 1.55.0 that uses both negative lookahead and lookbehind is below.

```
(?<!NoMatch)regexToMatch(?!NoMatch)
```