# how do i match squiggly bracket after a digit with regex

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I have many lines of text and they all end with a number followed by a squiggly bracket:

```
...9}
...8}
...4}
...3}
etc...
```

but I also have other lines with squiggly brackets but the character before is not a number. How can I match all squiggly brackets that only have a number before them?

I've tried the following so far but it selects both the number and the digit:

```
[0-9]} 
[0-9]?(})
```

also, I'm using the regex in atom's find & replace interface

Comment: Can you use lookbehind?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not sure what atom allows, sorry :/

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171447/lookbehind-assertion-regex-in-atom-editor

Comment: Try it and see, modern JS does have lookbehind now (who knows how modern spec-compliant Atom is, but no harm in trying)

Comment: Also, if you're trying find-replace, to keep the digit, you might be able to capture it normally (without lookbehind) and then replace with that captured group, plus whatever you want to replace the `}` with

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you show an example?

Comment: Just a guess, find `([0-9])}$` replace with `$1},` or maybe `\1},`

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the following:

```
(\d)\}$
```

and replace with:

```
$1},
```

This should match any line which ends in a number followed by a closing bracket.

If your editor supports lookbehinds, you may instead try:

```
(?<=\d)\}$
```

and then replace with:

```
},
```

Comment: it's giving me both the digit and the squiggly

Comment: Why does that matter to you?  Are you actually planning to do a replacement or something?

Comment: yessir, trying to replace the squiggly with `},` I have about 100 lines of code, trying to transform them into objects